# R "str" equivalent in perl

Tags: string, r, perl, structure

How do you get the data structure of an object in Perl?

I can easily do this in R  using str -

```
    str(data)
```

I wonder if there is similar one in Perl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can dump out the structure of an object using the `Data::Dumper` module.

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($data);
```